# Searching for an int* in C

Tags: c

I'm new to programming but Im trying to write a code were I can search after "pictures" that are in my staff. but this current code is not working as I would want to beacuse I can only type in one pic and then the program crashes.

```
typedef struct staff {
    char id[12];
    int *pic;
    int imagecount;

} staff;

int main (void)
{
    int employeecount = 0;
    int pic = 0;
    int test[3] = { 1, 2, 3 };

    staff mystaff[100] = { {"111", test, 3}, {"222", test, 3} };

    employeecount = 2;

    printf ("type in a pic you would like to search after\n");
    scanf ("%d", &pic);
    for (int i = 0; i < employeecount; i++) {
        if (strstr (&mystaff[i].pic, pic)) {    //// here im guessing? 
            printf ("%s      ", mystaff[i].id);
            printf ("%d ", mystaff[i].pic);
        }
        printf ("\n");


        return 0;
    }
}
```

any one got any ideas on how to do this? and yes it has to be *pic because this is a part of another small program im trying to do.

Comment: At first grance, `scanf("%d", pic);` is wrong.

Comment: `"//// here im guessing?"` **hint:** Never guess in C. Look it up. It will save you hours of time and frustration. That is what the man-pages are for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be using a string function (`strstr()`) to search for integers, that will not work. You need to explicitly look for the integer:

```
bool staff_has_pic(const staff *s, const int pic)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < s->imagecount; ++i)
  {
    if (s->pic[i] == pic)
      return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

then call that from `main()` instead of `strstr()`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < employeecount; i++)
{
    if (staff_has_pic(&mystaff[i], pic))
    {
        printf("%s has %d\n", mystaff[i].id);
    }
}
```

Also, fix the way you get the number:

```
if (scanf(" %d", &pic) != 1)
{
  printf("**Failed to get picture number\n");
  exit(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Function `strstr` look like this:

```
char* strstr (const char* str1, const char* str2);
```

You call:

```
if (strstr (int **pic1, int pic2) != NULL) {}
```

Comment: `strstr ` is only for null terminated char*